# WPF: Analyse XamlParseException from UserControl in .dll

Tags: wpf, powerbuilder, xamlparseexception

I have a custom WPF UserControl in a DLL file. I access the UserControl from PowerBuilder via OleObject (COM). I'm trying to create an instance of the UserControl (code in .NET dll).
Everything works fine when I'm using it via COM from C++, but in PowerBuilder, I'm getting this error message:

[Error Message](http://www.bilder-space.de/show.php?file=09.10h3a9ImBcEwwkgHP.png)

Can you help me to figure out, what the problem is?
Tell me, if you need some more information.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. :)
Had to load the assembly WPFToolkit.dll and System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll manually via Assembly.LoadFrom("...");
Now it works!
I think you will have to load all assemblies which contain custom classes which are used in the xaml this way.